# Wicket fragments, missing closing tag

Tags: java-8, wicket

I'm trying to follow the example given in [Wicket manual](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_working_with_markup_fragments). It is my understanding that, according to the manual, my code should generate an HTML form with a single checkbox. It doesn't. What am I misunderstanding here?

In particular, I'm getting the inexplicable exception in somewhat Borat-ish English:

```
org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupException: Close tag not found for tag: <div wicket:id="formElement">. For Fragment Components only raw markup is allow in between the tags but not other Wicket Component.. Component: [Fragment [Component id = formElement]]
```

At least the closing tag is there allright, isn't it?

HTML body part:

```
<body>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <form>
    <div wicket:id="formElement">
      <wicket:fragment wicket:id="chk">
        <input type="checkbox">
      </wicket:fragment>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
```

Java part:

```
public Home() {
    RepeatingView rv = new RepeatingView("formElement");
    Fragment chkbox = new Fragment("formElement", "chk", rv);
    rv.add(chkbox);
    this.add(rv);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
<body>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <form>
    <div wicket:id="formElement"></div>
      <wicket:fragment wicket:id="chk">
        <input type="checkbox">
      </wicket:fragment>

    <input type="submit" value="request">

  </form>
</body>
```

and:

```
  public Home() {
    RepeatingView rv = new RepeatingView("formElement");
    Fragment chkbox = new Fragment("formElement", "chk", this);

    rv.add(chkbox);
    this.add(rv);
  }
```

Unfortunately, the "fragment" is not reusable because of hard-coded `wicket:id` which is both used *to find* the chunk of HTML markup and *to add* it to the target container. And you cannot add two components with the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

Wicket Fragment is an inlined Panel. That is, you just put its Java code in the Java file of the markup provider and its HTML in the HTML code of the markup provider.

The problem in your case is that you are missing an HTML element which will consume the HTML generated by the Fragment.

I'll explain it with Panel because I think it is easier, but they are more or less the same. When using a Panel you need to declare something like `<div wicket:id="myPanel">` and then in the Java code something like:

```
add(new MyPanel("myPanel", ...));
```

Wicket will render MyPanel and use the produced HTML as a child of `<div wicket:id="myPanel">`.

With Fragment it is the same - you need:

- a declaration: `<div wicket:id="someId">`
- a markup: `<wicket:fragment>` (just like `<wicket:panel>`)

Comment: Thanks, I understood how it works. What seems utterly ridiculous is that one can "add" a particular fragment to a particular parent only once because of hard-coded, immutable id. As noted in my answer, the question for me now is how to reuse the same fragment, say, to auto-generate web forms. But that would be another question. Besides, I've done it already with 2 Thymeleaf templates.

Comment: For this you will need to use a repeater, e.g. RepeatingView or ListView. With those you can have many children (panels, fragments, any component). So you can dynamically decide which Fragment to use for each child. Apache Isis (http://isis.apache.org/) Wicket viewer uses this to autogenerate web forms dynamically based on your entity class.